# Javascript form validation by the code inside a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js01.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<form id="frmReg" method="post" onsubmit="valRegs()" action="memb_area/register.php">
```

Why the function valRegs() (code is placed inside js01.js file) is not executed, except I drag the code inside html file ?
How can I be sure that valRegs() is always executed before and not after code inside register.php file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making sure that the script with your validation is **below the form in your html**.

This is because you are trying to bind to a non-existent element when the script runs.

Alternatively you should wrap your script inside a jQuery `$(document).ready()` or by creating an onload function.

Comment: Hm and what about if js code is in separate file ? There is no before and after in this case ?

Comment: In your html structure you need to have your script tag below the form, does that make sense?

Comment: Sam, You're right. I replaced script tag below the form and it works. ThankYou. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solution `Sam` suggests, there is also a possibility if the `js01.js` contains errors, and the function is placed after the point of error. So use the broswer inspect to make sure there is no error within the js file.